# what is the replacement for module ActionController::UploadedFile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

I have been trying for far too long to get the docraptor rails example to save my generated PDF to Amazon S3 with Rails 3.0.7.  It appears that ActionController::UploadedFile has been replaced by ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile, but I get the error `'wrong argument type Class (expected Module)'` when I try to use that class to extend my file object.

Here is the source.  Am I using 'extend' incorrectly?  How can I do what I'm trying to do here?  Really, all i want to do is specify the name of the file that gets uploaded to S3 with Paperclip.

```
def create_pdfdoc(document_content)
  DocRaptor.create(  :document_content => document_content, 
                     :document_type    => 'pdf',
                     :name             => self.title.tr(' ','_'),
                     :test             => true) do |file, response|

      file.extend(ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile)
      file.content_type  = response.headers["content-type"]
      name = self.title.strip.gsub(/\s/, "_").gsub(/\W/, "").underscore.downcase
      file.original_filename = "#{name}.pdf"

      if response.code == 200
        self.pdfdoc = file
      end
  end
end
```

Comment: in the end, I just bagged it.  I set a local variable to the name of the file I want to save (self.pdfdoc) and paperclip handles the rest.  it worked out.

Answer (score 2):

in the end, I just bagged it. I set a local variable to the name of the file I want to save (self.pdfdoc) and paperclip handles the rest. it worked out.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing like answering a question 3 years later...

For anyone who runs into this in the future, this is the "right" way to do it:

```
DocRaptor.create(options) do |file, response|
   upload = ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile.new({
      :filename => 'test.pdf',
      :type => response.headers["content-type"],
      :tempfile => file
    })
end
```